# Combining multiple columns into one new column, while keeping the original column

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark, sql-null

I have below table, where I am trying to merge the columns in yellow in one column, while maintaining the original columns; the data in the highlighted yellow columns is populated based on the interaction type they fall into if the interaction type is null that means it doesn't fall into the interaction type category:

Would appreciate any help or guidance on how I can approach this

[image]

Expected outcome:
[image]

Comment: And what results do you want?

Comment: One new column that combines information from all six columns only if its not null, I have added another screenshot above for expected outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*,
    coalesce(
        svc_proc, 
        interest, 
        transtypekey, 
        connectivity_name, 
        vm_entreprise_program,
        channels
    ) as interaction_details
from mytable t
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-`null` value of the arguments list.